# Determine what CSV file version/type I am receiving so I can add it to a model

Tags: c#, csv, asp.net-core-2.1

I currently get sent a CSV file and dependant on what device the users are using, it can be in one of several formats.

The arrangement of the headers (and the associated column data)can be in a different order and sometimes extra columns are there and sometimes they are not.

The problem I currently have is that sometimes the `Reading (%Rh)` and `Reading (°C)` is getting mixed up and the `Elapsed` ends up getting temperature readings in it.

I always want to have the following columns (not necessarily in this order): `Index, Date, Time, Reading (°C), Reading (%Rh)`

For example,
Format 1:

```
Index, Date, Time, Reading (°C), Reading (%Rh)
```

Format 2:

```
Index, Date, Time, Reading (%Rh), Reading (°C)
```

Format 3:

```
Index, Date, Time, Reading (°C)
```

Format 4:

```
Index, Date, Time, Elapsed, Reading (°C)
```

Format 5:

```
Index, Date, Time, Elapsed, Reading (°C), Reading (%Rh)
```

Format 6:

```
Index, Date, Time, Elapsed, Reading (%Rh), Reading (°C)
```

I was going to create models based on each of the formats, then test to see if they match, but this seems a bit clumsy.

I want to be able to determine what the header names are and what order they are in so I can apply the relevant data to the model.

```
public class MyModel {

        public int ReadingNumber { get; set; }        
        public string ReadingDate { get; set; }        
        public string ReadingTime { get; set; }          
        public double Temperature { get; set; }
        public double Humidity { get; set; }
}
```

My question is, how can I test for which version of the file I am receiving, by analyzing the header names.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I have a much longer and more advanced routine in my core code, but essentially you want to parse the first line into headers and then subsequent lines get read into a `Dictionary` containing the information you want.

```
const string MYCSV = @"....";

IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> ReadFile()
{
    IDictionary<int, string> headers = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(MYCSV))
    {
         if (headers.Count == 0)
         {
             headers.AddRange(
                line.Split(',')
                    .Select((nm, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, nm));
             );
             continue;
         }

         IDictionary<string, string> record = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         record.AddRange(
           line.Split(',')
               .Select((val, i) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(headers[i], val);
         );
         yield return record;
    }
}

void GatherData()
{
     foreach (IDictionary<string, string> record in ReadFile())
     {
           int readingNumber = record["Index"].Parseint();
           ....
     }
}
```

Comment: How does that reference the differing header configuration. Is it a case of dealing with the return value?

Comment: I added a little more code for clarity, but this lets you reference the data by the header name without having to worry about the index.  For columns that don't exist, they can simply be ignored.  Of course, I left out all of the error checking, etc...  You could also build the original record class that you had from the dictionary and then your other code would be unchanged.